# Local itemType Ref - Microdata

Tags: html, microdata

I have just begun working with Microdata and added a simple AggregateRating to a clients website.

That’s working fine, however the client wants me to change the `itemType="http://schema.org/AggregateRating"` to `itemType="http://[His Website]/AggregateRating"` by simply copying the page.

I only started looking at Microdata yesterday, but I’m sure its not going to work simply by copying the page to a local file, and I suspect it’ll do more harm than good.

Can someone please confirm this is a bad idea? An explanation I can take back to him would be very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are right, that is a bad idea and is a completely incorrect use of microdata.

Think of "http://schema.org/AggregateRating" as a word in a common language. It's a word that everyone knows, which is how Google knows what it means. Schema.org is thus like a dictionary of terms.

What the client is asking you to do is basically like asking you to take the word "Dangerous" and change it to "Thomasgerous". No one will understand what you're trying to say.